# Are there lower standards for what answers are not nonsense than there are questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

Are there lower standards for what answers are not nonsense than there are questions? I feel the onus has been put on someone asking a question to show they know what they are talking about. That is absurd state of affairs, if so.

Why?